# Comparar Iput passado pelo usuário com itens de uma lista em Python

Tags: python, lista

Conforme o código abaixo

produtos = ['Milka com oreo', 'Nutella', 'Laka', 'Doce de Leite', 'Biscoito Passa-tempo', 'Dentaduras Fini',
'Bis Chocolate Branco', 'Amendoim Japones', 'Sonho de Valsa','Ouro Branco', 'Baton', 'Kinder ovo', 'Tortuguita',
'Fandangos', 'Pringles', 'Ruffles']

precos = [13.50, 9.00, 5.00, 6.00, 2.30, 4.99, 3.99, 2.00,1.00, 1.00, 0.75, 7.40, 1.20, 6.60, 13.00, 7.00]

estoque = [9, 10, 13, 4, 23, 6, 15, 8, 40, 34, 20, 12, 21, 5, 3, 7]

resultado = []

print ("Escolha o Produto desejado!!!")
print()
for i in range(16):
tupla=(produtos[i],precos[i], estoque[i])
resultado.append(tupla)
print(i, tupla)

Saída

0 ('Milka com oreo', 13.5, 9)
1 ('Nutella', 9.0, 10)
2 ('Laka', 5.0, 13)
3 ('Doce de Leite', 6.0, 4)
4 ('Biscoito Passa-tempo', 2.3, 23)
5 ('Dentaduras Fini', 4.99, 6)
6 ('Bis Chocolate Branco', 3.99, 15)
7 ('Amendoim Japones', 2.0, 8)
8 ('Sonho de Valsa', 1.0, 40)
9 ('Ouro Branco', 1.0, 34)
10 ('Baton', 0.75, 20)
11 ('Kinder ovo', 7.4, 12)
12 ('Tortuguita', 1.2, 21)
13 ('Fandangos', 6.6, 5)
14 ('Pringles', 13.0, 3)
15 ('Ruffles', 7.0, 7)

Preciso inserir um input no qual o usuário escolhe o produto desejado informando o codigo refente a tal

Ex: Usuário escolheu 11 então é retornado Kinder ovo, 7.4, 12.

Comment: Você [já perguntou isso e teve a pergunta fechada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/559811/70) pelos problemas descritos no quadro. Resolva os problemas da pergunta original, editando-a (tem link no quadro com orientações). Para evitar desencontro de informações o espaço de comentários foi suspenso nessa postagem, mas está aberto na original do [link fornecido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/559811/70).